Problem sending HTTP request to Docker container
I started the docker container with the command docker run -d -p 6000:5000 webapi , it runs a C# ASP.NET Core application on the localhost:5000 port. When I try to send a GET request to the URL http://localhost:6000/api/Users on the host machine using Postman (It should just return the entire list of users), it says Error: socket hang up. If you go inside the container and try to send the same GET request to the specified URL only with port 5000, everything will work. What could be the problem?

I suspect that your containing is binding to localhost:5000 (which is a "not really" network only available to other processes in the container). What you want (generally) is to bind it to 0.0.0.0:5000 instead which will make it available to the container runtime so that your --publish=6000:5000/tcp will make it accessible from the host's port 6000.

Could you pls help check whether you could visit 0.0.0.0:5000 inside the container? If not, maybe you can try to change the launchSettings.json file in your ASP.NET Core project, maybe "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5000" to "applicationUrl": "http://0.0.0.0:5000"
